# User privileges mess up in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have one big problem with php my admin database, here is the problem:
When I start xampp and start my sql and apache server, enter inside phpmy admin from localhost, I had about 7-8 databases. On one database I change user privileges and refresh, after that I do not have any database, any users and I can't create a new database. I try to solve the problem on stack overflow forum, but I didn't find the solution. Can you please check and respond me how to fix this problem? Maybe I can recover and databases too, bu I didn't export them anywhere. If I can only fix to create a new database, the error I get I try to fix but in vain.Here is the error in attachment.

Thank you in advance.

I tried to fix error 1044 but I didnt fix it.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCzyW.jpg)

Comment: _"Here is the error in attachment"_, ehhhhhhhh where??

Comment: Sorry for delay, I upload picture